# How to properly layout the plot

Tags: python

So this is what I have so far:

```
text="Enter data:"+"\n"
num=input(text).split()
num.sort(key=float)    


list = []
def plot():
   for x in num:
      if x not in list:
          list.append(x)
          if len(x) == 3:
              print('\n%s -'%x[:-2], end=' ')  
              print((x)[-1], end=' ')
          else:
              print('\n%s -'%x[:-1], end=' ')  
              print((x)[-1], end=' ')

plot()
```

The output of this code when Input = 12 31 10 42 69 35 is:

1 - 0 
1 - 2 
3 - 1 
3 - 5 
4 - 2 
6 - 9

but I want the first digits to only print once followed by their corresponding second digit/s (in increasing order) like this:

1 - 0 2
3 - 1 5 
4 - 2 
6 - 9

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to organize first your data in that way, i.e. group all numbers which start with the same digit. Only after that, print them. Besides the question... don't use global variables, Pass `num` as an argument to `plot`. Rename `list` to some other name which is not already used and declare it within the function, not outside.

Comment: additional to @zvone's comment: "x" is one letter of your input string at a time, so len(x) will always be 1. I do not fully understand what you want to achieve with len(x) == 3 (I guess some sort of sub-list with lenth 3?), but this if-branch will never be reached.

Comment: @ChristianKarcher since '12' is one of my input, its length will be 2. As for the len(x) == 3, it will take into account float numbers like '6.9' which has a length of 3.

Comment: oh, correct, i was missing the .split() after the input, my bad.

Comment: You mention an input like `6.9`, but I cannot figure out what could be the output in that case.

Comment: Also, how do you want to treat single digit numbers?  I'd say that your problem is not carefully defined, you should [edit] your question and try to clarify at least these issues.

Comment: @gboffi its 6 - 9. And for single digits, I'd just convert them to float first, sorry for not pointing that out

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain the requested behavior, also explain what you want to be output in the case of, say, a 3 digit nubers etc, thank you.

Comment: @gboffi Thanks for the answer, for now I'm satisfied with christian's answer. I'm just trying to tweak his code so it can accept 3 or more digits numbers (123 -> 12 -3) without it being interfered by len()==3 which is for the float ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While fully agreeing to zvone's comment, here's a quick correction to make your code work:

```
text="Enter data:"+"\n"
numbers=input(text).split()
numbers.sort(key=float)

first_numbers = []
def plot():
    for current_number in numbers:
        if current_number[0] not in first_numbers:
            first_numbers.append(current_number[0])  # first number logging
            if len(current_number) == 3:
              print('\n%s -' % current_number[:-2], end=' ')
            else:
              print('\n%s -' % current_number[:-1], end=' ')
            print(current_number[-1], end=' ')
        else:  # first number has already been printed, only print the second
            print(current_number[-1], end=' ')

plot()
```

Comment: `if len(current_number) == 3:` can be changed to  `if '.' in current_number:` so it can include 3 digit numbers that arent float. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:**

```
text="Enter data:"+"\n"
num=input(text).split()
num.sort(key=float)

def plot():
    current = None
    for x in num:
        x = str(x)
        if x[:1]==current:
            print(f" {x[1:]}", end="")
        else:
            print()
            print(f"{x[:1]} - {x[1:]}", end="")
            current = x[:1]

plot()
```

**OR**

```
text="Enter data:"+"\n"
num=input(text).split()
num.sort(key=float)

lst = {}
def plot():
    for x in num:
        x = str(x)
        value = lst.get(x[:1], [])
        value.append(x[1:])
        lst[x[:1]] = value

    for key, val in lst.items():
        xx = " ".join(val)
        print(f"{key} - {xx}")

plot()
```